# Batch rename multiple files by modification date

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, rename

I got a bat script for rename files by their creation date but I need to adjust the code below to made to rename files by modification date.

```
@echo off

set Folder=%userprofile%\desktop\Images

For /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /od /tc /a-d /b "%Folder%"') do call :Rename "%%a" "%%~nxa"
exit

:Rename
set /a Counter+=1
ren "%Folder%\%~1" "%Counter% %~2"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: From what I got you just have to change /tc by /tw in the dir part.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dir command,  `dir /T:W` but on NTFS this time may not be reliable or accurate.

Comment: Thanks I got it, but now the script names the first file by modification time with last number

Comment: Where do you set the %Counter% variable to an initial value?

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off

setlocal && cd/d "%UserProfile%\desktop\images\."

for /f usebacktokens^=* %%i in (`^<con: dir /O:-D /T:W /A:A /B`
)do set/a "_x+=1" && cmd.exe/v/c "ren "%%~dpnxi" "!_x! %%~nxi""

dir/o:n/t:w/a:a/b . & endlocal & timeout /t -1 |echo=iS Done!..
```

---

For the attempts I made, it works if inverting `-` order `/O:-D` with `/T:W`:

```bat
dir /O:-D /T:W: /A:A /B
```

---

- **[`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**